# Add columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to add value of 3 columns into one new column but there is a problem!
problem is that the value of columns is constant!!! but it should change from one column to another one!!!!

```
SELECT
    query,
    RESPECT,
    INTELLECT,
    STRENGTH,
    SEL,
    EXPERIENCE,
    GUN,
    DOG,
    CAR,
    CASH,
    BANK_CASH,
    STRENGTH + INTELLECT + SEL AS RES2
 FROM P
```

Comment: If the value of your columns is constant, why would you need to store it in a database?

Comment: Show the results you are getting and the results you expect, so we can see the difference?

Comment: o_O.. kindly provide an example..

Comment: Those are some amusing column names :)

Comment: Question, do different guns give strength bonuses?  If so, are they a fixed amount or a % of current strength?  If the latter you may want to rethink your computed column.  Just sayin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you have the concept of a **computed** column which might work for you here. You can define a new column to be an expression of other columns, e.g. in your case:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.P
  ADD RES2 AS Strength + Intellect + Sel
```

Now, your table `P` would have a new column `RES2` that is the sum of `Strength`, `Intellect` and `Sel`. This column will be different for each row - based on the other values for the three fields that make up `RES2`.